# alarm dosen't play android

Tags: android

I try to implement alarm in my android application, this is my code below, I don't know where I did it wrong,  please help, thanks.

OnetimeAlarmReceiver.java
         import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

```
      import android.content.Context;
       import android.content.Intent;
        import android.widget.Toast;

       public class OnetimeAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {
    @Override 
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

            }

NoteEdit.java

              private int alarm=1;
         public void setAlarm() { 
    if(alarm!=1){
        alarmTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        alarmTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        alarmTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        alarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        alarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)-alarm); 
        alarmTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);   
        alarmTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); 

    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(NoteEdit.this, OnetimeAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NoteEdit.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 
    //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1234567, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime.getTimeInMillis(),  sender);
    Toast.makeText(NoteEdit.this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
        mBodyText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
    }
}


         public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            case PICK_ALARM:
        final CharSequence[] items1 = {"5 minutes before", "10 minutes before", "15 minutes before","20 minutes before", "30 minutes before", "1 hour before"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder2.setTitle("Select your alarm");
        builder2.setItems(items1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {    

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {   
                setAlarm(); 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items1[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                if(items1[item]=="5 minutes before"){
                    alarm =5;
                }else if(items1[item]=="10 minutes before"){
                    alarm =10;
                }else if(items1[item]=="15 minutes before"){
                    alarm =15;
                }else if(items1[item]=="20 minutes before"){
                    alarm =20;
                }else if(items1[item]=="30 minutes before"){
                    alarm =30;
                }else if(items1[item]=="1 hour before"){
                    alarm =60;
                }
            }
            });
        AlertDialog alert1 = builder2.create();
        alert1.show();
        break;



        }
```

Comment: How far you reached? Did u get any Toast message?

Comment: yes, i get the toast message, but It just the alarm doesn't play.

Comment: Did you get Toast message `Alarm worked.`??

Comment: yes, so where do I get the audio file thanks

Comment: I do get that toast message, but not in the right time that I set

Comment: it's like I get that toast meeage straight away after I set the alarm, I think the time setting is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your minute calculation. suppose current time in minute is 0 and your alarm value is 5 then set alarm time minute it will get -5. Please recheck your code again whether your logic is right

Edit:

```
if(alarm!=1){
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)); 
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);   
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); 

}
```

when you set the alarm use the following code:

```
alarmTimeInMillis = alarm*60*1000;
     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime.getTimeInMillis()-alarmTimeInMillis,  sender);
```

Comment: alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime.getTimeInMillis()-alarm*60*1000,  sender);  this is the code I tried but still not working, I get the toast message "alarm worked" straight away after I set the alarm, so I think the time is still wrong but don't know how to change, thanks

Comment: up the function  dateAndTime.get()

Answer (score 0):

If you get Toast message `Alarm worked.`, to play audio, you have to add following code
Create a `raw` folder in `res` and add  audio file

```
MediaPlayer mpaudio=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.audio_file);
```

`mpaudio.start();`

try this also

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

Here alarm will start after 10 sec

Insted of `OnetimeAlarmReceiver.class` try this `MyAlarmService.java`

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {
MediaPlayer  mpaudio;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return null;
    }
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mpaudio=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.maya);
    mpaudio.start();
    }
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: MediaPlayer mpaudio=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.audio_file); I tried this code, but it give me an error said:The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (OnetimeAlarmReceiver, int)

Comment: Replace `this` with `context`

Comment: I tried this, and the error is gone, but program ded, do I need ot change the manifest.xml file? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I don't have a raw folder in my res folder, so I created one inside the src folder and put a audio file inside it, but the program dead after I run, what am I doing wrong, thanks?

Comment: Create raw folder in your project res folder